# Changing default terminal in Codeblocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Windows cmd does not support ANSI colour codes and there are a lot of better terminals in the internet. I'm new to code::blocks and want to change the default terminal. What I did is:

**Settings>Environment** and I just can't change "Terminal to launch console programs" field. How can I do that?

Comment: me too... that's quite a bump.

Answer (score 39):

I think you can't able to change default terminal on Window's Operating System because none other is present there. But if you are using Linux like Ubuntu you can change it's default command window as `gnome-terminal --title=$TITLE -x` in place of `xterm -T $TITLE -e` on Settings>Environment>"Terminal to launch console programs"

Comment: ANSI escape sequences does not work with windows cmd. It is not even close to resolve my problem as it is Code::Blocks related, not c++. Thanks for you help anyway.

Answer (score 6):

[image]1) Open Settings in Code blocks from title bar
2) Choose environment from It
3) there is an option to terminal to launch console program (drop down) to run program from there you can choose whatever terminal you want from there

Answer (score 1):

The cmd window used in code::blocks will support ansi escapes in windows but it has to be enabled. Try this:

```
HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
if (hConsole != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {    
   DWORD mode = 0;
   if (GetConsoleMode((hConsole, &mode) {
      mode |=0x0004;
      SetConsoleMode(hConsole, mode);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the title bar of the console window -> properties -> font/or layout tab.