# Why does ansi escape doesn t work on codeblocks, and how to fix it?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, codeblocks

For example this piece of code :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "\033[31m" << ".";

    return 0;
}
```

prints a red dot in a visual studio console, but in a codeblocks console it prints this  :

```
[31m*
```

If anyone knows how to fix this problem for the codeblocks console.

Thanks

Comment: It is non-portable. Some terminals support them, some don't.

Comment: @Klaus and so on how do i change the output color in a console like codeblocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every console can use control code sequences as it likes. There are numbers of different standards. If you like to control your output with a given set of control sequences, you have to satisfy that the used console is able to handle them. Some terminal emulators can be configured to use a special emulation, some others have no control sequences at all.

Take a look on [Terminal Emulations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_terminal_emulators) to get an idea how many different terminal emulations are available. And the Wikipedia article lists only a subset!

> and so on how do i change the output color in a console like codeblocks

First: Take a look on the user manual and search for "terminal emulation". Maybe you find the used control set, maybe you will find out that your console in your used IDE has non! If so, it is like it is.

Maybe you can use a different terminal emulator for your editor:
[How to change used terminal in Code::Blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13900328/changing-default-terminal-in-codeblocks)

Comment: @BenjaminStarck: See my last edit: You can change the console if you like. So cou can start a console which supports your control sequences.